# Spark - extract values from dynamic maps

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to flatten some values from a Map[String, SomeComplexType].

The following works:

```
df.select("complex_field_name.some_key.complex_type_field").show()
```

But it seems like it is only working in cases the key exists.

I've tried using:

```
df.select(expr("
case when complex_field_name.some_key is not null
then complex_field_name.some_key.complex_type_field
else null
end as new_field_name"))
```

But it seems to still fail on missing key. Any ideas?

Comment: of course it fails if the key does not exist. How can it return a value for a non-existent key? What do you expect?

Comment: but thats why i'm trying to wrap it with case when key not null

Comment: It doesn't give NULL on a missing key - it crashes because the key does not exist. How do you supply `some_key` to the query? Manually?

Comment: spark version ??